# Extract values from Json variable and perform java post processor action

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I have the following json value stored in a variable. The json is extracted from other response.

DAYS:

```
[
  {
    "date": null,
    "absent": false,
    "holiday": false,
    "exam": [],
    "blocked": []
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-21",
    "absent": true,
    "holiday": false,
    "exam": [],
    "blocked": []
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-26",
    "absent": false,
    "holiday": false,
    "exam": [],
    "blocked": []
  },
  {
    "date": "2021-02-27",
    "absent": false,
    "holiday": false,
    "exam": [],
    "blocked": []
  }
]
```

1. I want to get all dates from this variable DAYS using Json XPath extractor where date is not null and the exam array is empty.
2. Then I want to process the dates with java processor so I could get the first date that is niether Saturday nor Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single shot using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def dates = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).findAll { date -> date.exam.size() == 0 && date.date != null }

   for (Map entry : dates) {
       def date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', entry['date'])
       if (!date.toDayOfWeek().name().equals('SUNDAY') && !date.toDayOfWeek().name().equals('SATURDAY')) {
           vars.put('date', entry['date'])
           break
       }
   }
   ```
3. If the search succeeds you will have the date stored as `${date}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I got the error No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [[{ }]]: I use my input as vars.get('DAYS') since the response data contains alot of information, not only the above input (contains all calenders of students and the input is for one specific student)